# Appium IOS: how to find locators by XY coordinate positions on screen?

Tags: python-2.7, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to automate my IOS build and i have only .ipa. I have experience with Android automation using Appium.  For Android i use UIautomatorviewer to locate UI element positions for XY on the screen. I can not figured out how to find XY position in IOS build. My app made in Unity and class name, id, xpath are not supported. Only solution is XY positions. I have never done IOS automation and need lil bit help. 
Looking forward to hear any information.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop

Comment: And also: https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md

Comment: Thanks, yes, i have done this from links you sent. The second is SetUp. I can use info from first Link, because it displays only id, class or xpath. My app does not support it. It is blank for me. Same thing with Android, that is why i have used coordinates by XY position.